# Unable to retrieve values from dynamically created select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form that populates a select drop down using JavaScript + a PHP variable (that contains JSON information). The JavaScript creates the drop down perfectly however I can't work out how to retrieve the posted value on form submit.

I've tried retrieving the value using the simple post method to post the value, and retrieve it on the same page however nothing is passed through, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST['save_settings_button']))
{
$site_name = $_POST["Site"];
}
?>

 <form name='myform' method="POST" action=''>
        <label for="Site">Site:</label>
        <select id="Site"></select>
        <div class=""><input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" name="save_settings_button" value="Save Settings" /></div>
    </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var jsonData = {
          "Table": <?php print $output;?>
      };

         $(document).ready(function () {
             var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -</option>';

          for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Table.length; i++) {
                 listItems += "<option value='" + jsonData.Table[i].id + "'>" + jsonData.Table[i].name + "</option>";
             }

             $("#Site").html(listItems);
         });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put any name for dropdown(`SELECT`) input add `name="Site"` then you can get input from it.

```
<form name='myform' method="POST" action=''>
    <label for="Site">Site:</label>
    <select id="Site" name="Site"></select>
    <div class=""><input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" name="save_settings_button" value="Save Settings" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sometime its happen brother.

Comment: If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you. @user1419810

Comment: my action URL doesn't recognize the value for the Select tag which has set through js, please help me on this I am using PHP as backend.